# Administrator is not able to update or view authenticator app settings associated with users in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, multi-factor-authentication

I have set up MS Authenticator App in MFA for azure. I can see app is link with profile user logs in to myapps but as administrator I cannot manage this setting. Can you please help me with solution in scenario where end user faces any issue with MFA for Auntheticator app how can administrator help on getting it resolved?

Answer (score 0):

As an Administrator kindly go through the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/user-help/user-help-auth-app-faq) to get a detailed information about the MS authenticator app .

If you have any further questions with specific queries kindly let me know.

Comment: Thanks for your reply it was very helpful. I have one question as that how Microsoft or user's organization can forget and unregister the old device if they can't view it in user profile